# Third file is attached only, through phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I m sending an Email with multiple attachments through phpmailer. The loop i used to send multiple attachments is The Message going with attachment, only contain the last choosen file, and the first two or one files are not sent. Is there a problem with Loop. Please :

```
     foreach($_FILES as $key => $file){
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path .basename($file['name']);

   if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
   echo "the file ".basename($file['name'])." has been uploaded";
   }else {
  echo "there was an error";
   }
  mail->AddAttachment($target_path);
   }

     <form id=
       "mail" name="mail" method="POST" action="<?php $PHP_SELF ?>" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="uploaded" multiple="" />
    <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit"  />
    </form>
```

Comment: If you check the uploads/ directory after this runs, how many files are there? If there's only 1, maybe you're overwriting the first file on each successive loop. If all three are there...well...that's another issue

Comment: There is only one file. How can i resolve this rewriting issue.. Please tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[]` to the name of the input field, like so:

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded[]" multiple="" />
```

Each file uses the same name "uploaded", so "uploaded" gets replaced by each successive file that is processed. By adding brackets, each successive file is added to the "uploaded" array instead. Here's the `$_FILES` array I get after adding `[]`:

```
Array
(
  [uploaded] => Array
    (
      [name] => Array
        (
          [0] => file4.txt
          [1] => file1.txt
          [2] => file2.txt
          [3] => file3.txt
        )

      [type] => Array
        (
          [0] => text/plain
          [1] => text/plain
          [2] => text/plain
          [3] => text/plain
        )

      [tmp_name] => Array
        (
          [0] => C:\temp\php95.tmp
          [1] => C:\temp\php96.tmp
          [2] => C:\temp\php97.tmp
          [3] => C:\temp\php98.tmp
        )

      [error] => Array
        (
          [0] => 0
          [1] => 0
          [2] => 0
          [3] => 0
        )

      [size] => Array
        (
          [0] => 7
          [1] => 2850
          [2] => 27
          [3] => 231
        )
    )
)
```

Index `0` in each array is one file, index `1` in each array is the next file, and so on.

---

This is also how you would get the values of multiple checkboxes of the same name. (See [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#77344) for an example.

---

Here's how you could loop through the uploaded files.

```
// first get the count of how many files are uploaded
$numFiles = count(array_filter($_FILES['uploaded']['name']));

for ($i = 0; $i < $numFiles; ++$i) {
    $target_path = 'c:/temp/' . basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i]);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
        echo "the file ".basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name'][$i])." has been uploaded<br />";
    }
}
```

Notice how I use `$i` in a `for` loop to keep track of the index of the current file.

(If you're wondering why I called `array_filter()` to get the count, it looks like a blank entry automatically exists if you don't upload any files. `array_filter()` removes that blank/invalid entry.)

Comment: Warning: basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/dev01/maiarn/mail.php on line 20

Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/dev01/maiarn/mail.php on line 22

Comment: $target_path = $target_path .basename($file['name']);
 
if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_path)) These are the two lines on which errors come.

Comment: @HanyaIdrees You can't just pass the arrays as they are; you need to loop through them and move each file individually. I'll add an example. To clarify, multiple files won't show up as different entries in the `$_FILES` array; they will all show up under the "uploaded" entry in `$_FILES`.

Comment: I m new, so not understood. Can u give some example code. How to do that loop

Comment: @HanyaIdrees Ok, I just added a loop example. I hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much.. After 2 weeks of googling, and confusion. U helped me really

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a unique number to each file on each iteration through the loop like this:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($_FILES as $key => $file){
    $counter++;
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path .basename($file['name'], ".jpg") . $counter . ".jpg";



if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
   echo "the file ".basename($file['name'])." has been uploaded";
   }else {
  echo "there was an error";
   }
  mail->AddAttachment($target_path);
   }

 <form id=
   "mail" name="mail" method="POST" action="<?php $PHP_SELF ?>" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="uploaded" multiple="" />
<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit"  />
```

Comment: This dnt work. Even it changes the File to currupt, by adding a 1, like daynay.jpg1 . And only one file is tranferred as before